# Dynamically add client's role in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm in a situation where I'm not sure how to proceed.
I need it when I add a new role to make it visible as an option next to the current user's roles.
The roles are visible as checkboxes.

For example I have users, every user is something like:

```
user [param1, param2, param3, roles[{role1}, {role2}]]
roles [
  {description: 'description 1', key: 'desc1'},
  {description: 'description 2', key: 'desc2'}
]
```

After some amount of time I need to push a new role in roles, let's say

```
{description: 'description 3', key: 'desc3'}
```

When I loop thru the clients with *ngFor, the roles that a client already has are visible as marked checkboxes.

The question is how to add the new checkbox as not marked checkbox next to the other roles that the client has?

I have some solution in mind but it is related to many loops that I would like to avoid and I'm searching for а smarter solution.

Comment: what do you mean by marked checkbox , what exactly you want to do with the new checkbox?

Comment: If you edit your question, add the solution you have in mind and explain what you think is wrong with it, it will be easier for others to help you.

Comment: "what do you mean by marked checkbox , what exactly you want to do with the new checkbox?"
 - to be added next to the other options for the current user so the admin for example to be able to mark it if needed.

 "If you edit your question, add the solution you have in mind and explain what you think is wrong with it, it will be easier for others to help you."
- my solution is to add a new parameter checked: boolean and when a new role is added to be added for all existing users with checked: false (no access if false) but in this way I have to loop thru all users with every new role.

Answer (score 0):

What if you do a *ngFor displaying all roles dynamically for each user:

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users">
<!--Here what you want to show about the user -->
  <div *ngFor="let role of roles">
    <mat-checkbox [checked]="doUserHaveThisRole(user,role)" (change)="changeUserRole(user,role)">{{role.description}}</mat-checkbox>
  </div>
</div>
```

and ts file:

```
doUserHaveThisRole(user: User, role: Role): boolean {
  return user.roles.indexOf(role) !== -1;
}

changeUserRole(user: User, role:Role):void{
  if(doUserHaveThisRole(user,role)){
     const index = user.roles.indexOf(role);
     user.roles.splice(index,1);
     return;
  }
  user.roles.push(role);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).